# Scientific Matrix Library for Windows 8 Store apps. (C++/CX)

Tags: windows-8, c++-cx

Are there any work being done in porting either Eigen/OpenCV Matrix libraries for windows 8 Store Apps? For both arm/x86.

If i need a matrix library for my windows store app. Are there anything out there worth using?  Alternative, how would i port Eigen or OpenCVs library for Windows 8 Store Apps.

I think its called a C++/CX Runtime Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your language/ecosystem.

1. If you are targeting .NET and the CLR, there's [Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/)
2. If you are using native code (C++/CX) then you should be able to use existing libraries as-is, including OpenCV and Eigen

Comment: I was planing on creating a SDK that could be used by both .NET CLR and using a native code backend to do the matrix calculations. Meaning my code/SDK will be in Native C++. Have i understood it correctly, that creating a C++/CX wrapper to my library i can call into it from .Net CLR? Also - i assume that some work would be needed to compile either eigen/openCV for ARM?

Comment: Interop is a large topic, and you'll find plenty of articles on it on MSDN. In a nutshell, you shouldn't have any problem creating a Windows Runtime component ( in C++/CX ) and calling it from .NET - that's what it's there for. However, regarding ARM, your life will be much easier if you stick to pure .NET, as the JIT compiler can automatically emit the ARM instructions for you. As you've guessed, there may well be work involved in compiling native C++ libraries to target ARM.

Comment: Thanks. I guess i will try play around with it. Guess the OpenCV people are going to provide a solution for compiling OpenCV for Windows Store Apps at some point.